# How to extract list of unique items from a column in a large data set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to extract unique Article Numbers from a big database inside excel. It will go up to 15000-20000 unique article numbers. I have tried to use the code below to solve this, and it does work. But the document gets so slowed down by this and thus becomes a pain to work with. This will be used every day so at this pace it would be unbearable to work with. Do you know any good ways of speeding this up? Read smt about binary search, but I don't know how to implement that into the code I have down below. Any help is appreciated:)

```
=IFERROR(IF(LOOKUP(2;1/(COUNTIF($A$1:A1;Unique) =0);Unique)= 0; "";LOOKUP(2;1/(COUNTIF($A$1:A1;Unique) =0);Unique) );"")
```

//The unique is just a named range, so it doesn't have to handle the full 20000 rows at all times

Comment: Probably the fastest way to do this is to copy column A to another column, and then go to Data -> RemoveDuplicates on that column.  No formula needed.

Comment: Which column is the data in?

Answer (score 0):

Oh that would work. I can write some vba code to perform that action :) Ty very much